# Add dynamic child views in expandableListView android

Tags: java, android

I have a ExpandableListView that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. I want to add childs of the ExpandableListView dynamically (for each child layout may be different) .Please Help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8937610/2722799 use this reference.

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnChildClickListener in your Activity and implemet this method..

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

   //Add new chid data in your list (ex ArrayLis or Array whatever you use)
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // BaseExpandableListAdapter's adapter...


  return true;
}
```

Is it work work for you?